# dispatch_async going in infinite loop

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

am developing an application where i have to get data from JSON and display in UITableView. Getting of data am doing in the background. But it seems to go in infinite loop.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath];
queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.events.app", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    [self load];
    //Need to go back to the main thread since this is UI related
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // store the downloaded image in your model
        Events *evObj = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        NSLog(@"evObj = %@",evObj);
        cell.textLabel.text = evObj.eName;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Detailed Text";
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    });
});
    // Configure the cell...



return cell;
}
```

Comment: You can not use asynchronous methods in a methods that has a return type. Since `UITableViewCell` is reused you could be modifying a cell which no longer bound to the same index path. Also you should not reinsert the cell in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` since this will call the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: @vitality This is not correct, you should perform UI tasks on the main thread. When dispatch them asynchronous the block will be added to main queue and executed in order.

Comment: @rckoenes indeed I don't know where my head was at just now :P

Comment: what i want is. the data am getting from JSON i want to do it on a background thread, and when it is completed i will update the UI thread to dispaly the data, but its going in an infinite loop. It downloading also and then displaying also . i used the following reference      http://blog.yangmeyer.de/blog/2012/12/16/uitableviewcell-subclasses-and-async-loading

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should not have calls to load the data or update cells from within it. As rckoenes says, get rid of the async stuff, but more to the point and more importantly, get rid of the calls to update cells from this method, which is what iOS calls whenever you update a cell.

Comment: @Nitin that article is performing async update of fields within a cell (which won't involve recursion), which is very different from calling to reload the whole cell (which does involve recursion). By the way, that article you link to has a serious flaw, that they fail to consider the possibility that the cell as scrolled off and been reused by another row of the table by the time the async call is done. It's unlikely (but still theoretical possibility) when doing the sort of stuff they reference, but not entirely unlikely if you're retrieving data from the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes into loop because sending `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` will trigger `UITableView` to ask your data source for another cell with `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

If you want to update cell asynchronously, you'll have to update a direct UI element, but avoid reloading the entire cell. If things don't update automatically you can send `-setNeedsDisplay` or `-setNeedsLayout` after updating.

Comment: hey guess what..... it worked. It was the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths that was causing it to go in infinite loop. Thanx buddy. I love SO

Comment: OMG guess what else worked. I removed the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths and placed it outside the dispatch loop and it worked like a charm... sometimes it funny how things work out ... hehe

Answer (score 1):

Just remove all the asynchronuos calls:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath];

   if(cell == nil) {
     /// load the cell.
   }


    // store the downloaded image in your model
   Events *evObj = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
   NSLog(@"evObj = %@",evObj);
   cell.textLabel.text = evObj.eName;
   cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Detailed Text";


   return cell;
}
```

Just move the `[self load];` to some other part of your code, like the `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: i tried moving it to viewdidload but then it does not update the numberofrowsinsection count .

Comment: Call [table reloadData] after loading.

Answer (score 0):

distinguish the data part from the ui part.

I.e.

call `[self load];` method just once, or the many times YOU need. Best place for this is viewDidLoad method or so.

The implementation for reloading data and presenting them in the uitableview might look like this  ( with GCD )

`dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.events.app", NULL);`

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
[self load];

//Need to go back to the main thread since this is UI related
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableview reloadData];

//don't forget to release your queue
dispatch_release(queue);

});
```

});

copy the implementation of `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{}`method from rckoenes and you're done;)

but remember one important thing. Your first thrown code causes a big overhead, you're downloading, parsing, and setting data each time this method gets called, at least 3times in the beginning when the uitableview loads itself and then every time you scroll it gets called as many times as many rows/cells you can see on the screen